# What happens to the TLB during a segmentation fault?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, tlb

If the TLB is responsible for caching virtual and physical addresses, then what happens to it when a process tries to access an address space that doesn't belong to it? Can the TLB also handle empty address spaces?

I asked my TAs for my OS course and they didn't really have a concrete answer, would love some help.

Comment: The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer) has a decent explanation of the basics. Pages that don't belong to you should not be cached, the TLB [gets cleared at every context switch](https://superuser.com/questions/253424/the-tlb-changes-whenever-a-program-does-a-context-switch).

Answer (score 2):

CPU designers expect that programs will rarely, if ever, access unmapped addresses. Therefore, the TLB usually<sup>1</sup> does not cache the fact that an address is unmapped. If the program does access an unmapped address, you'll have an ordinary TLB miss followed by a lookup failure in the actual page table, and it's the lookup failure that triggers the page fault. Similarly, if a page is mapped but not present, it won't<sup>1</sup> be in the TLB, because the expectation is that the cost of making the page present again will dwarf the cost of a page table lookup.

However, the TLB *can* cache the fact that a page is mapped read-only, non-executable, supervisor only, etc., so you can get page faults triggered directly by the TLB in those cases.

<sup>1</sup> I don't know *every* CPU design, it's possible that somebody somewhere tried making the TLB cache these things, but it's rare enough that I can't think of an example.